# Постановка запятой перед прилагательным

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Ты знаешь(,) красивый он.*
Ставится ли запятая после "знаешь"? Если да, то что мы выделяем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите [тут](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85_%D1%81_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/):

> **Примечание.** Вводные слова и сочетания слов:
> <...>
> з) призывают к вниманию: *верите (ли), видите (ли), **видишь (ли),** вообрази (те), вы знаете, вы понимаете, если хотите, если хочешь, заметь (те) себе, знаете (ли), знаешь (ли), как хотите, можешь (себе) представить, не поверите, не поверишь, поверь (те ), пожалуйста, помилуй (те), помните (ли), понимаете (ли), послушай (те), представь (те), представь (те) себе, прости (те) меня, сделай (те) милость, скажи (те) на милость, согласитесь*

Таким образом, мы выделяем *вводное сочетание.*